# Javascript regexp: how to create a single matching group

Tags: javascript, regex, browser, operating-system

**Scenario**

I am trying to get the operating system details from the `navigator.appVersion` property.

So I tried the `regexp.exec()` method:

`/\(([a-z0-9 \.]+)(?=;).*\)|\(([a-z0-9 \.]+)\)/i.exec(navigator.appVersion);`

And here are the outcomes in different browsers:

- Opera, Safari, Chrome

  `["(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)", "Windows NT 6.1", undefined]`
- IE

  `"[(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; rv:11.0)"_"Windows NT 6.1",undefined]`
- Firefox

  `["(Windows)", undefined, "Windows"]`

So I am pretty happy with the regexp definition, the matching group correctly get the OS details. But...

**Questions**

1. Why in the output array the matched group has got a different position across browsers?
2. What is the 'undefined' element of the output array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined is the group that didn't match. You have a single alternation, each with a capture group.

This is your regex in detail.

```
   \(
   ( [a-z0-9 \.]+ )              # (1)
   (?= ; )
   .* 
   \)
|  
   \(
   ( [a-z0-9 \.]+ )              # (2)
   \)
```

Not sure what you need to do, but you can use a single capture group to handle both

```
 # /\(([a-z0-9 .]+)(?:(?=;).*)?\)/i

 \(
 ( [a-z0-9 .]+ )               # (1)
 (?:
      (?= ; )
      .* 
 )?
 \)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand why there are three elements in the input array. DRY!!